# how to properly display ExtendedData in kml files?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, embed, kml

I'm trying to use google maps embed api v3 and geoxml3 (kml local parsing), everything seems to work but it doesn't.

First, kml file displays ExtendedData correctly in Google Earth
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI5tv.jpg)

Now, on Google Maps (Embed in my page)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQfcX.jpg)

Kml code:

```
<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#icon4</styleUrl>
<name>Nro Pobl:9</name>
<ExtendedData>
    <Data name="Poblador N°"><value>9</value></Data>
    <Data name="Extra Data"><value>Some Data</value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
<Point>
    <coordinates>-68.13332504,-42.8138761,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
```

It's something wrong with this code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps `<ExtendedData> | partially | 
untyped <Data> only, no <SimpleData> or <Schema>, and entity replacements of the form $[dataName] are unsupported.`

Comment: I'm not using <SimpleData> or <Schema> at all, just <Data> like the code I posted. Data tag, like I'm using its supported.